# Prevent Failure of complete Trigger

Tags: apex, api, trigger

I have an issue, which might be familiar with most of you all.

We are getting Cases from Oracle via Command Line Data Loader  Programs.

It is quite possible that one record has a data issue which might prevent it from getting created in Salesforce.

But the issue is the whole set of Records go into failure because of this one record.

I am handling  lot of logic in Before Insert trigger.

Is there a way to prevent the failure of whole records?

Thanks,
Chellappa

Comment: 1) Are you referring to the SFDC Data Loader program here or some other Data Loader?  2) Are only Case records being inserted or do your triggers insert other SObjects as well?

Comment: Can you clarify what type of data issue we are dealing with here? E.g. Is it being rejected by a validation rule, by Salesforce field type checking, by logic in the before insert trigger? I suspect it is the latter and you are using something like [sobject.addError()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the optional `opt_allOrNone` parameter that can be passed to most [Database methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm).

> The optional opt_allOrNone parameter specifies whether the operation
>   allows partial success. If you specify false for this parameter and a
>   record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed.
>   This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which
>   records succeeded, which failed, and why.

Comment: To the down voter: It's fine to vote an answer down if you disagree or believe it is incorrect. To help others understand why you voted it down, please leave a comment with the reason. Hopefully the answer can be improved to address any issues.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I will comment on your answer because I'm not sure it will work:
A "before" trigger won't fire any DML statements - things are done to the record under consideration and then the record is inserted. So there is no way to use the Database.insert(mylist, false) method. What do you think?

Comment: @DavidSchach Would incorrect data from an the API insert/upsert ever reach the before update trigger? It really depends on the data in question and what is rejecting it as invalid. A malformed datetime would be rejected at the API level.

Comment: Depends on what you're talking about. You are correct about malformed DateTime. Unique fields aren't evaluated until after the trigger has fired. But the all/nothing boolean is not available at all in a before insert trigger.

Comment: I'll see if I can get some clarification in the question. My experience with something like the Partner API was that a number of records could be inserted and a number fail with error reasons. I suspect it has to do with how the errors are being raised.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. Yes .. Database methods doesnt come in play here. The records are coming in from API. And we are using Command Line Data Loader programs. A simple Example for error is Null Pointer. exception. I am getting  10 records and one records is failing because i encountered a Null Pointer exception  on one record. It is failing the whole 10 records. And None of the records are geting inserted in the Case Object. Can we allow the other 9 to flow through.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel if you are able to remediate your production code base. If you don't want to refactor your production code, another option would be to set the commit batch size to 1, which would force each record to be submitted as a separate transaction. This is a very slow way to insert records, but might offer an option until you are able to remediate your trigger code. To do this, you will need to edit the process-conf.xml file for your dataloader command line files, take the loadBatchSize attribute, which might look like this:

```
<entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="100"/>
```

and change it like this:

```
<entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="1"/>
```